# The defined command not work in \ifdefined

Tags: output

Why this `MWE` doesn't work?

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myClass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myClass}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\def\fullname#1{\gdef\@fullname{#1}}
%
\ifdefined\@fullname
\def\myTable{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Some & Text\\
    \@fullname & Text
    \end{tabular}%
}
\else
    \def\myTable{Why not defined?!}
\fi
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myClass}
\begin{document}
    \fullname{Defined}
    \myTable
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you are testing the defined at the time the class is loaded, not when the code is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP structured it, the `\ifdefined` test was being performed as the class was loading.  Instead, it should be performed during the document phase.  I do that here by including the test in the definition of `\myTable`.

EDIT: I also changed the `\else` condition of `\MyTable` to actually print out the "warning", rather than merely to define it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myClass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myClass}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\def\fullname#1{\gdef\@fullname{#1}}
%
\newcommand\myTable{%
 \ifdefined\@fullname
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Some & Text\\
    \@fullname & Text
    \end{tabular}%
 \else
    Why not defined?!
 \fi
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myClass}
\begin{document}
    \fullname{Defined}
    \myTable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This time I'm the one beaten by a few seconds... `:-)`

Comment: @campa Maybe for today, but I'm sure the roles will soon reverse and you can again be the fastest `\draw` in the `.west`.

Comment: Thank you, but now when I comment the ```\fullname{Defined}```, doesn't work again.

Comment: @BahmanMirzakhani I see that in the `\else` condition of `\myTable` you only redefined `\MyTable` for a future use (and did not print out anything!).  I have changed the answer to actually print out "Why not defined?"  Perhaps this is easier to understand.